# How to get the content within ::before and ::after with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

I would like to parse a html site with the following code:

```
<div class="dates">
<div class="clearfix" id="datesDiv"></div>
::before
"some text" <span></span>
"some other text"
::after
</div>
```

How do I get just the "some text" and "some other text" with beautiful soup?

Neither a search with soup.find nor soup.select has worked for me. The result is always empty. 
When I look at the html code of the whole site, "some text" and "some other text" is missing in the html code as well. However "some text" and "some other text" are shown on the html site.
When I search it with selenium and the driver.find_element... function it works as well, but this is not what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that from your browsers debugger?

Comment: Beautifulsoup cannot handle dynamic content. You have to use selenium for these type of dynamic content. Once you have scrapped the data with selenium you can use bs4 to extract what you need.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic content is loaded via some other source, usually javascript.  If you can mimic the request being made by the javascript then you can get the data.  If the thing you are looking for is not in the source code of the page then you cannot just make the single request and get it using beautiful soup without subsequent requests to the actual source of the data.